# How to scrape element by background color python

Tags: python

i find myself facing a certain problem for a while.

I am looking to collect certain data from a website (https://www.pronosoft.com/fr/parions_sport/resultats-parions-sport-plein-ecran.htm?date=07-02-2020), but the problem is that I cannot target this data correctly.

The data I want to extract are the following:

- The winning odds of the football matches that have been played in the first column ( 1 N 2 )

Let me explain...

As you can see to get the odds of soccer matches i have a class called ==> class="m-s-0 m-c-22 m-376811"

with the m-s-0 refering to soccer matches m-c-22 refering to the compet and a m-376811 which refers to a specific match that we see in "value" = 376811

The winning odds are indicated by a gray background which is found in classes with multiple names like res_c res_baisse or res_c or res_c res_hausse etc

I'm looking to find out how to recover these elements using the background color because it seems to me the most effective way to do it.

I tried the following code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.pronosoft.com/fr/parions_sport/resultats-parions-sport-plein-ecran.htm?date=07-02-2020'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

soup.find_all('res_c', {"style":"background-color:#636364"})
```

But finding nothing it return an empty list, do you have an idea on how to proceed thank you in advance

Right now :

i now have something like this

```
odds = []
match = []
for match_row_tag in match_list_tag.table.tbody.findChildren('tr'):

# .find() will choose only the first result from the row
winning_odd_tag = match_row_tag.find('span', {'class':'res_c'})
sport_foot_tag = match_row_tag.find('span', {'class':'sport football'})
soup_foot = match_row_tag.find('a', {'class':'infos'})
match = []

if sport_foot_tag in soup_foot not in match and sport_foot_tag in soup_foot is not None:
    match.append(sport_foot_tag.parent.get_text().split("\n")[0])
    for matches in set(match):
        print(winning_odd_tag.string, sport_foot_tag.parent.get_text().split("\n")[0])
        odds.append(winning_odd_tag.string)
else:
    pass
```

with an oupout like this:

```
3,90 Everton - Leicester
1,23 Everton - Leicester
4,30 Everton - Leicester
1,22 CefnDruidsFC-TheNewSaints
1,42 Connah's Quay-Bala Town
1,10 Connah's Quay-Bala Town
3,40 Llandudno FC-Caernarfon
1,18 Llandudno FC-Caernarfon
2,85 Derby - Middlesbrough
1,09 Derby - Middlesbrough
1,28 Derby - Middlesbrough
```

But the thing is i would like the name of the matches to appear only once in order to get only the first value from my row

Someone got an idea why this is not working as expected ?

Answer (score 0):

This will iterate over the table rows and find the first span element with 'res_c' as a class, which is the odd in the first column with a grey background color:

```
match_list_tag = soup.find('div', {"id":"match-list"})

for match_row_tag in match_list_tag.table.tbody.findChildren('tr'):

    # .find() will choose only the first result from the row
    winning_odd_tag = match_row_tag.find('span', {'class':'res_c'})

    if winning_odd_tag:
        print(winning_odd_tag.string)
```

Comment: i'm not looking for the team names but only for the winnings odds found in the first 1 N 2 i did get the hole odds using `odds = soup.select(".res_c")`

Comment: will be ```match_list_tag = findAll(<params>)``` if you want see llist for result

Comment: .find() works here because you're finding one table called 'match-list'.

Comment: Really close to the expected result with the difference that in reality it does not make the difference between the first column and the following because it happens (sorry for this oversight of details my bad) as here [link](https://www.pronosoft.com/fr/ parions_sport / results-parions-sport-plein-ecran.htm? date = 01-01-2019) that the first column is empty and the next one is filled and there is the problem because we are only interested in the first column

Comment: In that case, one approach would be to get the team names tag, then test the 4th .next_sibling() to see if it has the attribute colspan="3".

Comment: What do you mean ? Because I was rather thinking of creating a generator that stores match names in a list and that adds a new odds only if the match name is not already present in it like : `if match_name not in match_row_tag...`